# How to draw a line in OpenGL without glBegin

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I looked at the code in [How to draw line in OpenGl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14486291/how-to-draw-line-in-opengl) but glBegin and glEnd are marked as deprecated. How are you supposed to draw a line in the current OpenGL version? I found articles that talk about using VBO, and articles that talk about `glVertexPointer` and `glColorPointer`, but there's *so much* framework around building these methods with the shader program compiling and linking and the vertex attribute bit twiddling. Isn't there a simple way to draw a line without using deprecated functions?

I tried this without success:

```
OpenTK.Vector2[] linepts = { new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(1, 1), new Vector2(50, 0), new Vector2(0, 50) };
int h = GL.GenBuffer();
GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, h);
GL.BufferData<Vector2>(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 16, linepts, BufferUsageHint.StreamDraw);
GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.LineStrip, 0, 4);
GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);
GL.DeleteBuffer(h);
```

I don't know if I'm even in the right ballpark using DrawArrays or if that method requires a whole mess of framework to go along with it, so I don't *necessarily* want to make *this* code work. I just want to find the simplest code for drawing a line that's advisable to use in modern OpenGL.

Comment: No, there is no simple way. Compile and link a shader program, create a VAO, VBO, set them up, and then call `DrawArrays()`.

Comment: Why not check opengl's official page?

Comment: Nope, that's definitely not the correct way to do this. You've fed OpenGL vertex data, but you haven't hooked that data up to vertex attributes. At minimum you also need a `GL.VertexPointer` call. If you want to avoid the fixed-function pipeline and go purely with shaders, then you need to establish attribute locations. That's your job in GL 3.0, there aren't pre-defined locations for this stuff anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the simplest program (using OpenTK) that I can create to draw a line.

```
using System;
using OpenTK;
using OpenTK.Graphics;
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL;

namespace OpenGLLine
{
   static class Program
   {
      static OpenTK.GameWindow gw;
      static int shaderProgram;
      static int vertexInfo;
      static int lineVertexBuffer;
      static int vertexCount;

      [STAThread]
      static void Main()
      {
         gw = new OpenTK.GameWindow(800, 600, OpenTK.Graphics.GraphicsMode.Default, "Game", OpenTK.GameWindowFlags.FixedWindow);
         Initialize();
         gw.RenderFrame += Gw_RenderFrame;
         gw.Closed += Gw_Closed;
         gw.Run(60);
      }

      private static void Gw_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         CleanUp();
      }

      private static void Initialize()
      {
         int vshader = GL.CreateShader(ShaderType.VertexShader);
         GL.ShaderSource(vshader, @"#version 130
            in vec2 vPosition;
            void main()
            {
               gl_Position = vec4(vPosition, -1.0, 1.0);
            }");
         GL.CompileShader(vshader);
         int fshader = GL.CreateShader(ShaderType.FragmentShader);
         GL.ShaderSource(fshader, @"#version 130
            out vec4 fragColor;
            void main()
            {
               fragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
            }");
         GL.CompileShader(fshader);
         shaderProgram = GL.CreateProgram();
         GL.AttachShader(shaderProgram, vshader);
         GL.AttachShader(shaderProgram, fshader);
         GL.LinkProgram(shaderProgram);
         GL.DetachShader(shaderProgram, vshader);
         GL.DetachShader(shaderProgram, fshader);
         GL.UseProgram(shaderProgram);
         lineVertexBuffer = GL.GenBuffer();
         Vector2[] lineVertices = { new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(.5f, .5f) };
         vertexCount = lineVertices.Length;
         GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, lineVertexBuffer);
         GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(lineVertices[0]) * vertexCount,
            lineVertices, BufferUsageHint.StreamDraw);
         vertexInfo = GL.GenVertexArray();
         GL.BindVertexArray(vertexInfo);
         int locVPosition = GL.GetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "vPosition");
         GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(locVPosition);
         GL.VertexAttribPointer(locVPosition, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false,
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(lineVertices[0]), 0);
         GL.BindVertexArray(0);
         GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);
         GL.UseProgram(0);
      }

      static void CleanUp()
      {

         GL.DeleteProgram(shaderProgram);
         GL.DeleteVertexArray(vertexInfo);
         GL.DeleteBuffer(lineVertexBuffer);
      }

      private static void Gw_RenderFrame(object sender, OpenTK.FrameEventArgs e)
      {
         GL.ClearColor(Color4.Black);
         GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);
         GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, lineVertexBuffer);
         GL.UseProgram(shaderProgram);
         GL.BindVertexArray(vertexInfo);
         GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.LineStrip, 0, vertexCount);
         GL.BindVertexArray(0);
         GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);
         GL.UseProgram(0);
         gw.SwapBuffers();
      }
   }
}
```